Alexa Auto Dialog Delegation strange error Python: Can&#39;t find skill bundle metadata for skillId amzn1.ask.skill
I am trying to use Dialog Delegation. I am working in Alexa Dev console. Auto Dialog Delegation is enabled in EditContactDetailsIntent. There are 2 handlers EditContactDetailsIntentHandler and InProgressEditContactDetailsIntentHandler below, but I get a strange error when trying to initiate the above intent sequence  that has no trace in CloudWatch logs:
{
  "type": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
  "message": "Can't find skill bundle metadata for skillId amzn1.ask.skill.GUID_HERE locale en-GB stage development"
}

2 handlers:
class EditContactDetailsIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return (ask_utils.is_intent_name("EditContactDetailsIntent")(handler_input) and
            ask_utils.request_util.get_dialog_state(handler_input) == "COMPLETED")

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        speak_output = "This is EditContactDetailsIntent initiated when phone number is complete."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class InProgressEditContactDetailsIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return (
            ask_utils.is_intent_name("EditContactDetailsIntent")(handler_input) and
            ask_utils.request_util.get_dialog_state(handler_input) != "COMPLETED"
        )

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        currentIntent = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
            .add_delegate_directive(currentIntent)
            .response
        )


To resolve the issue, locate the following JSON block in the Alexa Developer Console’s JSON editor:


"dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "TechSupportAppointmentIntent",
                    "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentDate",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.5137408571304957813049571345134513451345.1617658477706"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "appointmentTime",
                            "type": "AMAZON.TIME",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": false,
                            "prompts": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
        }



If you find dialog with inside intent, try removing it. After doing so, save the changes and test the skill again to see if it resolves the problem. Removing the dialog configuration can sometimes help if automatic delegation or prompts are interfering with intent functionality.
